# dart-eclipse plugin crashing after installing dart plugin

Tags: eclipse, dart, dart-polymer, dart-eclipse-plugin

I am using a new installation of Eclipse Luna SR2. I install the dart-eclipes update from the site https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/release/latest/editor-eclipse-update/. The version 1.10.0-dev.1.9 (rev 45311) installed. However, after restarting eclipse after the installation prompt to restart, the Luna logo is visible for a short while and then crashes (is no longer visible). There is no console output or anything.

Old eclipse metadata have been removed from the installation folder.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

The dart plugin checks for a 'dart-sdk' directory in your eclipse installation directory.

If you have `dart` and `eclipse` unzipped in your home `~/bin`, then this should do the trick:

```
$ cd ~/bin/eclipse
$ ln -s ../dart/dart-sdk/
```

Now you should be able to start `./eclipse`.

Update:
I have submitted this issue to the dart bug tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23335

Answer (score 1):

Warning: the suggested symbolic link workaround will erase the target dart-sdk directory when doing an upgrade from inside Eclipse. If you don't want this to happen just copy the whole directory instead of linking.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the dart directory you dowloaded.
2. Copy the dart-sdk directory.
3. Paste it directly in your eclipse directory. (the directory
   containing eclipse.exe)

Bonus : 
To get the error messages when Eclipse crashes you can find the log in the directory you specify when you try to launch Eclipse.
--> "MyJavaProjects"\.metadata\.log.txt